# How to call a pointer to a member function which is retrieved from a map?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call a pointer to a member function, which I retrieve from a map. The call `th.fpObjHandler(md, evd, tokenIdx)` seems erroneous, I've tried various different syntaxes (e.g. `.*` and `->*`), but I cannot seem to get it right. Hopefully somebody here is able to help.

```
struct TokenHandler
{
    int tokenIdx;
    eventDataStatus_t (Schema::*fpObjHandler)(MessageData &md, EventDataImpl &evd, int &tokenIdx);
};

Schema::event(MessageData &md, EventDataImpl &evd)
{
    int tokenIdx = 0;
    std::map<std::string, TokenHandler> tokenHandlerMap;
    tokenHandlerMap["timeInterval"] = { -1, &Schema::timeInterval };

    // ..
    // ....

    TokenHandler th = tokenHandlerMap.at(key);
    if (th.fpObjHandler != NULL) {
        th.fpObjHandler(md, evd, tokenIdx); // THIS RESULTS IN ERROR
        //..
        //...
    }
}

eventDataStatus_t Schema::timeInterval(MessageData &md, EventDataImpl &evd, int &tokenIdx)
{
    //..
    //...
    return OK;
}
```

> Schema.cpp:111:54: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call
>   pointer-to-member function in ‘th.TokenHandler::fpObjHandler (...)’,
>   e.g. ‘(... ->* th.TokenHandler::fpObjHandler) (...)’
>                        th.fpObjHandler(md, evd, tokenIdx);
>                                                         ^

Comment: @ZeroUltimax, if I would write `(th.*fpObjHandler)(md, evd, tokenIdx)`, than this would result in the error `fpObjHandler was not declared in this scope`, therefore I consider this problem different and not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need an instance of the class `Schema`, then use `.*` or `->*`, something like:

```
Schema schema;

(schema.*th.fpObjHandler)(md, evd, tokenIdx);
```

Or, as you are already in a method of `Schema`:

```
(this->*th.fpObjHandler)(md, evd, tokenIdx);
```

Comment: `event` is a member function of `Schema`, so `(*th.fpObjHandler)(md, evd, tokenIdx)` should be enough I think.

Comment: @Thx. now it indeed compiles. This does seem highly ineffective do, because now fore every call I need to create an instance of Schema.

Comment: @Rakete1111: member function pointer requires an instance to be called.

Comment: @Gio: So you probably want simple pointer function and make the method static.

Comment: @Rekete1111, I've just tried your tip, but unfortunately that doesn't work. (invalid use of unary '*' on pointer to member.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, ok. then maybe `(this->*th.fpObjHandler)(md, evd, tokenIdx)`?

Comment: Eureka!! That works.